# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xhtml2pdf' under Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

New to Google App Engine.
Building entirely using Google Cloud Shell - mainly learning the platform before doing serious development.
Completed all possible future requirements, except for showing graphs on webpage and downloading PDF. This question is about downloading PDF

I create a new folder PDF

Under appengine_config.py I add:

```
vendor.add('pdf')
```

I run command:

```
pip install -t pdf/ xhtml2pdf
```

I get an error message:

```
ipython 5.10.0 has requirement prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4, but you'll have prompt-toolkit 2.0.10 which is incompatible.
```

I create a Class PDFHandler.py with code starting as:

```
from io import StringIO
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
```

I write rest of the code and run Application using **python3 main.py**, I get error as:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xhtml2pdf'
```

What is it that I am missing?
Is there a better way to have ability to download custom PDF?

Comment: For the requirement from ipython on prompt-toolkit version, there is a conflict with requirement from mssql-cli 1.0.0 has requirement prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0. So I ignored that portion which may be contributing?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your issue by running `pip install -t pdf/ xhtml2pdf` from the Cloud Shell, as the following error shows up:

> Successfully built xhtml2pdf pyPdf2
> ipython 5.10.0 has requirement prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4, but you'll have prompt-toolkit 2.0.10 which is incompatible.
> Installing collected packages: webencodings, six, html5lib, pyPdf2, Pillow, reportlab, xhtml2pdf ...

If you follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/python/setup#installing_and_using_virtualenv) documentation to create a virtual environment on your Cloud Shell and use the following command `pip3 install -t pdf/ xhtml2pdf --upgrade` to install the required dependency (or in general create a requirements.txt file, add the necessary dependencies there and run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`) you shouldn't see the prompt described above anymore.

In an additional note I wouldn't recommend using the Cloud Shell as a development environment, as it is  a tool meant for rapid prototyping and testing.

In general please refer to the [following documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/setup#linux_1) to setup a Python development environment.

And if your application requires some PDF handling I would recommend you exploring the use of App Engine Flexible environment to install the specific dependencies that are required for your PDF processing in a separate service that can be called by your main application via HTTP. Find more information about this [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/flexible-for-standard-users#when_to_use_the_flexible_environment).